# Look rotation with offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I’m working on a mechanism to control the position and rotation of an object around an anchorPoint relative to a controlPoint in 3D space. The object can have any initial rotation, necessitating the use of a rotational offset in order to maintain a relative alignment when the controlPoint is moved. Neither the control nor anchor points exist within the unity scene hierarchy as they’re stored as Vector3’s. The object however, utilizes unity’s Transform and may have one or more parent objects each with their own rotation.

The expected behavior is much like that of a local rotation gizmo where you click on the ring of the gizmo to set the rotation of the object.

I've tried without success to implement this using FromToRotation, LookRotation as rotations from identity as well as incremental rotations from the previous rotation state.

The below was the closest i got, however if the object or it's parent have a Z rotation upon calculating the offset, the object then rotates as expected but also includes an undesired roll around the look axis.

```cs
public Vector3 anchorPoint = Vector3.zero;
public Vector3 controlPoint = Vector3.left;

Quaternion rotationOffset = Quaternion.identity;

//Called when the object is "attached" to the anchor to store the difference between it's rotation and the directional vector from the control to the anchor
public void StoreOffset() {
    //The unit vector pointing from the controlPoint to it's anchorPoint
    Vector3 controlFwd = (anchorPoint - controlPoint).normalized;

    //Generate a rotation using the direction vector while respecting the objects local up.
    Quaternion lookRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(controlFwd, transform.up);

    //Subtract the object's rotation from the lookRotation to determine the rotational offset between the two.
            //Invert the offset rotation to save on calculations during update
            rotationOffset = Quaternion.Inverse(Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation) * lookRot);
}

//Called any time the control point is moved to update the objects rotation
public void UpdateRotation() {
    //The unit vector pointing from the controlPoint to it's anchorPoint
    Vector3 controlFwd = (anchorPoint - controlPoint).normalized;

    //Generate a rotation using the above direction vector while respecting the objects local up.
    Quaternion lookRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(controlFwd, transform.up);

    //Assign the new look rotation to the object then apply the offset rotation.
    //ToLocalRotation is a Quaternion extension that converts rotations from world to local space
            transform.localRotation = (lookRot * rotationOffset).ToLocalRotation(transform);
}
```

**Example Animations**

The first .gif shows the correct functionality so long as the parent object has no rotation.

The second .gif shows errant rotation if the parent has a Z rotation of 10°

[image: Expected Rotation]
[image: Errant Rotation]

Comment: It's still a little unclear what `controlPoint` is meant to do. Maybe walking through some examples could help. What is supposed to happen if control point is set to be some distance in front of the object, then `StoreOffset` is called, then the control point is set to be directly above the object, `UpdateRotation` is called, then some time later, the control point is set so that it is on the opposite side of the object (at this point the back of the object) then `UpdateRotation` is called. How is the object supposed to be oriented after `UpdateRotation` is called each of those times?

Comment: Also it's not quite stated but it seems that both `controlPoint` and `anchorPoint` are in global space. Is that correct?

Comment: @Ruzihm controlPoint and anchorPoint are in global space. Using your example, assuming the anchor is the origin, when StoreOffset is called, the object's forward is facing the controlPoint so the offset rotation would be the inverse of the LookRotation from the controlPoint to the anchorPoint (respecting the objects local up). Due to that specific offset, the object would always rotate to face the controlPoint.

Comment: Right, but what directions would the objects local up be? The opposite direction from the control point's original position after the first `UpdateRotation`, then the same direction from the control point's original position? or would the local up not change on the 2nd call? We can say the angle is actually only changing 89 degrees then 179 degrees and just speak approximately

Comment: Assuming a starting object rotation of local forward is aligned with global forward, The first update (+89° around local x axis) would cause up to move from global up towards global back. The second rotation (+179°) would depend on whether the shift from top to bottom favored the the local right, or the local up axis. (If it helps, controlPoint movement occurs incrementally by user drag and not by value assignment.)

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Is it correct that the object's `position` plays no part in this, Only the object's `rotation` and the two Vector3 fields?

Comment: Ultimately, the object will also have a positional offset and thus rotating around the anchorPoint, but that part of the code i had working and pulled out during debugging as i narrowed down where i went wrong. I've generated 2 .gifs showing the desired motion, and an erroneous motion and will add them to the question shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So before storeoffset happens, you have a current rotation R. You want to calculate an offset X such that from the local axes at rotation R which would produce the look rotation where local forward = control->anchor and local up ≈ the up from R.

That is to say,

```
R * X = lookrotation(anchor - control, transform.up)
```

So, in order to find X, multiply both sides of the equation by inverse(R) on the left side:

```
inverse(R) * R * X = inverse(R) * lookrotation(anchor-control, transform.up)
                 X = inverse(R) * lookrotation(anchor-control, transform.up)
```

So, the end of `StoreOffset` should rather be:

```
rotationOffset = Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation) * lookRot;
```

Then, in `UpdateRotation` you have X and the lookRot with an up from a ~close-enough~ transform, so solve for R by multiplying both sides by inverse(X) on the right:

```
R * X              = lookrotation(anchor-control, transform.up)
R * X * inverse(X) = lookrotation(anchor-control, transform.up) * inverse(X)
                 R = lookrotation(anchor-control, transform.up) * inverse(X)
```

So, the end of `UpdateRotation` should rather be:

```
transform.rotation = lookRot * Quaternion.inverse(rotationOffset);
```

Or, since it's likely that `UpdateRotation` will be called much more often than `StoreOffset`, do the inversion before the assignment:

```
rotationOffsetInverse = Quaternion.inverse(Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation) 
                                           * lookRot);
// ...
transform.rotation = lookRot * rotationOffsetInverse;
```

So, altogether:

```
public Vector3 anchorPoint = Vector3.zero;
public Vector3 controlPoint = Vector3.left;

Quaternion rotationOffsetInverse = Quaternion.identity;

Quaternion GetControlLookRot()
{
    // The unit vector pointing from the controlPoint to it's anchorPoint
    Vector3 controlFwd = (anchorPoint - controlPoint).normalized;

    // Generate a rotation using the direction vector while respecting the 
    // objects local up.
    return Quaternion.LookRotation(controlFwd, transform.up);
}

// Called when the object is "attached" to the anchor to store the difference between 
// its rotation and the directional vector from the control to the anchor
public void StoreOffset()
{
    rotationOffsetInverse = Quaternion.inverse(Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation) 
                                        * GetControlLookRot());
}

// Called any time the control point is moved to update the objects rotation
public void UpdateRotation() 
{
    // Assign the new look rotation to the object then apply the offset rotation.
    transform.rotation = GetControlLookRot() * rotationOffsetInverse;
}
```

Comment: It looks like how `rotationOffset` was calculated in the question got changed while I was writing this answer....

Comment: Yes, i made an update when i loaded the .gifs while we were discussing as i had accidentally resolved the parent's X throwing out the rotation, getting scene to animate for recording the gifs, but still had the Z causing issues. Originally i had the lookRotation and the transform.rotation swapped in. rotationOffset = lookRot * Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation); I'll run your guidance through testing in the morning as the office is closing now.

Comment: Once i changed line that assigns the rotation in UpdateRotation to transform.localRotation = (lookRot * rotationOffset).ToLocalRotation(transform); this guidance worked for both X & Z rotation. Thank you it's frustrating for a multi day hangup to be caused by something as simple as having one's multiplication order swapped. (although i could have sworn i checked for this previously...)

Comment: @Reahreic Happy to have helped. Just wondering - is the conversion to a local rotation then assignment to `localRotation` rather than `rotation` a choice for efficiency? I'm not sure I understand why it would not do the same thing when assigning the global rotation to `rotation`.

Comment: I honestly don't know, until i changed it the last test case didn't pass. Although if i change it back this morning, it passes all test cases regardless so either my computer is gas-lighting me or i'm loosing my mind. That said, while i'm not in a performance bind yet, i'll take any performance gains i can get.